# jquery hasClass matching element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In jquery can I combine "closest" or Parents() with "hasClass", so it will give me a closest element with given class, if it exists on a page?

```
var matchingDiv = $(this).closest('div').hasClass('SomeClass')

if ( matchingDiv != null )
{
   //we found matching element now manipulate it

}
```

I will always have either one matching div element, or none.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var matchingDiv = $(this).closest('div.SomeClass')

if ( matchingDiv.length )
{
   // use length to find if there was a match.
   // closest() will always return an object.
}
```

If this doesn't work, perhaps post some html. Maybe there's a problem there?

Comment: It does work, thanks a lot. Documentation states that it returns null, if no matching elements found

Comment: @Patrick, you could also shorten to just `if (matchingDiv.length)` since 0 will evaluate to `false`

Comment: @Doug, Very true. More concise and concise is good. Will correct.

Comment: @VictorS - Actually the documentation for closest() states ' *The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element* '. (Had to check on that one.) No matter what, you're getting an Object.

Answer (score 1):

try this, closest takes a selector:

```
var matchingDiv = $(this).closest('div.SomeClass')

if ( matchingDiv != null )
{
   //we found matching element now manipulate it

}
```

Comment: I've tried it before it doesn't work for the reasons unknown to me, it should imo

Comment: strange, how about this: 
 $(this).parents('div').find('.SomeClass:first')

Comment: This does not work. You test for null will always be true, even if there was no match.

Comment: That seems to be the case, how should I change test then to make it valid?

Comment: @VictorS - I've added an answer with the proper test.

Answer (score 1):

[Closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) takes a selector so you can do this:

```
 var matchingDiv = $(this).closest('div.SomeClass')
```

Your next line is a problem, you [should](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx#tip22) be checking a jQuery result like so:

```
if ( matchingDiv.length )
{
    //we found matching element now manipulate it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check whether the current element itself might be the ancestor you're looking for..  You can use a combination of `is()` and `closest()` as follows :

```
var matchingDiv = $(this).closest('.SomeClass');

matchingDiv = matchingDiv.length == 0 ? (matchingDiv.is('.SomeClass') ? matchingDiv : null) : matchingDiv

if ( matchingDiv != null )
{
   //found matching element 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if this will work or not?

Off the top of my head, I would say that it does, because the jQuery paradigm is based on chaining together jQuery functions.

Answer (score 0):

[doc for closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
var matchingDiv = &(this).closest('.SomeClass')

if ( matchingDiv != null )
{
   //we found matching element now manipulate it

}
```

Comment: Sounds like he specifically wants a 'div' element with the class.

Comment: @patrick, I included the link of the documetacion of "closest", I think @VictorS can view the documentation and complete what you need

Answer (score 0):

The difference between closest() and parents() is that parents() can give you more than one element if your selector matches more than one. (for what that's worth here)